# How to show the focus able slider image of android

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery, android-gallery

I am a android developer and i want to  develop an application. In this app, i want  to show a gallery image slider.In this  slider ,the focus able image see should large and place to middle point and other image  see should be small to same bellow picture.

[image]

I also try the below code .It is also show the large focus able image but not same .

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("position", "" + arg3);

            ProductByCategoryData productByCategoryData = AllProductByCategoryData
                    .getAllProductByCategoryData(arg2);
            Constant.producdata = productByCategoryData;

            Intent i = new Intent(ModeltypeActivity.this, OrderDetailInformation.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }


    });

    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (lastSelectedView != null)

            {
                lastSelectedView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                        lowLavelWidth, lowtLavelheight));// 150, 200//100, 150
            }

            arg1.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(heighLavelWidth, heightLavelheight));// 220,
                                                                        // 315//150, 200
            lastSelectedView = arg1;

            int vectorPosition = arg2;
            ProductByCategoryData product = AllProductByCategoryData
                    .getAllProductByCategoryData(vectorPosition);
            product_name.setText(product.getProduct_name());

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Now how to show the gallery slider  image same to above image.please help to me.It is Possibel  ?

Comment: have you found the answer for this question?